# npm test --codecoverage doesn't generate report

Tags: angular, karma-runner, angular-cli

Have no ideas why when I hit

```
npm test --codecoverage
```

All test is being executed, however I see an empty '/coverage' folder with no single report. I use **angular-cli**

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the CLI installed globally, The command is

```
ng test --code-coverage
```

If you want to use the `npm scripts`, you will need to do

```
npm test -- --code-coverage
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the command is

```
npm test --coverage
```

There is no check on arguments passed, so you can put in anything you like without it throwing an error. But to trigger code coverage, I believe you have to put in `--coverage`

Comment: Thanks, but "npm test --coverage" doesn't generate coverage.. where I can see output?

Answer (score 0):

the command to run the test with coverage is

`npm test -- --coverage`